# meaning of share power

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of share power in the following sentence?

> The Jannayak Janta Party, which counts the Jat community as its support base, and the BJP **share power** in Haryana after bitterly fighting each other in elections; in western Uttar Pradesh, a sharp polarisation on religious lines had brought sections of the community closer to the party in recent years.

[To Read The Full Article](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/formula-failure-the-hindu-editorial-on-bjps-loss-in-punjab-civic-polls/article33883310.ece?homepage=true)

Comment: The words here have their dictionary definitions.  They have power, which is *legal or official authority, capacity, or right*, and they are sharing it, meaning that they *partake of, use, experience, occupy, or enjoy with others* that power.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the state government of Haryana is not dominated by a single political party, but power is *shared* between the two parties mentioned.